# Prometheus blackbox-exporter ICMP ping monitoring configurations all targets are showing up

Tags: prometheus, icmp, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am setting up monitoring N number systems UP/Down status with Prometheus Blackbox-exporter ICMP.

blackbox-exporter configurations:

```
modules:
  icmp:                                                                                                                                                                                       
    prober: icmp                                                                                                                                                                              
    timeout: 5s                                                                                                                                                                               
    icmp:                                                                                                                                                                                     

      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
```

Prometheus configurations:

```
  global:                                                                                                                                                                                       
  scrape_interval:     15s                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  external_labels:                                                                          
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'                                                                                                                                                                
scrape_configs:                                                                                                                                                                               
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prometheus:9090']
  - job_name: 'blackbox'                                                                                                                                                                      
    metrics_path: /probe                                                                                                                                                                      
    params:                                                                                                                                                                                   
      module: [icmp]

    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                           
      - targets: ['192.168.1.29', '987.234.121.1']                                                                                                                                                            
        labels:                                                                                                                                                                               
          group: 'Build'                                                                                                                                                                   
      - targets: ['161.92.248.21', '161.92.3.185', '10.10.4.18']                                           
        labels:                                                                                                                                                                               
          group: 'RND' 
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackboxexporter:9115
```

blackbox-exporter probes results are accurate and looks fine 
  Note: Results are showing failure for non-reachable targets this looks fine

```
Recent Probes
Module  Target         Result   Debug
icmp    192.168.1.29    Failure Logs
icmp    192.168.3.185   Failure Logs
icmp    161.92.248.21   Success Logs
icmp    192.168.4.185   Failure Logs
icmp    987.234.121.1   Failure Logs
icmp    192.168.1.29    Failure Logs
icmp    192.168.3.185   Failure Logs
icmp    161.92.248.21   Success Logs
```

[image]
Prometheus Results are not accurate. this are showing all the targets are UP
 Note: expected results are failure targets should show down with 0/1

```
blackbox (5/5 up) 
Endpoint    State   Labels  Last Scrape Scrape Duration Error
http://blackboxexporter:9115/probe
module="icmp" target="161.92.248.21"    UP  group="RND" instance="161.92.248.21" job="blackbox" 1.43s ago   1.522ms 
http://blackboxexporter:9115/probe
module="icmp" target="192.168.1.29" UP  group="Build" instance="192.168.1.29" job="blackbox"    5.548s ago  1.501s  
http://blackboxexporter:9115/probe
module="icmp" target="192.168.3.185"    UP  group="RND" instance="192.168.3.185" job="blackbox" 1.944s ago  1.501s  
http://blackboxexporter:9115/probe
module="icmp" target="192.168.4.185"    UP  group="RND" instance="192.168.4.185" job="blackbox" 3.09s ago   1.501s  
http://blackboxexporter:9115/probe
module="icmp" target="987.234.121.1"    UP  group="Build" instance="987.234.121.1" job="blackbox"   2.796s ago  1.506ms
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe querying `probe_success` metric in Prometheus will give you the expected result.

We usually create our basic "up/down" alerts from this metric when using blackbox-exporter.

Comment: Thanks you @nsmeds. Yes I got this, probe_success query is the query.